# initaialize variable once in android app then use and save that for futher reuse

Tags: java, android, android-button

My question is this--
I have an app that should limit a button click ,say upto 5 clicks ,in whole lifetime of the app.
Preciously at 6th click of a certain button it should not read that OnClick event ,no matter how many times the app is opened or closed.
Guys im an average programmer and im enough aware of both android and java.Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: You can use sharedpreference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: When you say 'lifetime of the app'. Do you mean during the app lifecycle or for as long as the app is installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Preferences to store the value and retrieve it.

```
// Write Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("ClickCounter", counter);
sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();

// Read Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int clickCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt("ClickCounter", 0);
```